# Dpkg: After comparing config files, how do I revert back to make my choice?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, terminal, dpkg

I'm part way through a fairly large apt-get upgrade which had 65 packages to be updated.

I've gotten to a config file "merge conflict" where both my local config (containing a licence key) and the new config file have changes (new config options).

I hit "D" to compare the two files and after concluding I'd like to keep my current config file, I've realised I've no way to get back to the prompt to make my decision to keep the current file.

I'm reluctant to hit CTRL+C as I'm not sure this won't kill the entire upgrade process.

I've read this but can't find anything related to my issue: http://www.cyberciti.biz/ref/apt-dpkg-ref.html
Any help is much appreciated. Right now I've the terminal waiting for input! :D

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? What the hell is wrong with this question?!?

Comment: I am not 100% sure ,and could not find the specific docs for that, but i think it was related to the default editor choice. ie: vi/vim = press :q, nano/emacs press ctrl+q
sadly i cant reproduce a merge conflict right now.

Comment: Hi, just a q after the colon got me back to the choice selection and I'm away again. Thank you. Please post as an answer.

Comment: i have added the answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have the vi or vim editor as default and this was used by dpgk.

You can quit the merge window with:

> :q

it is the same keys as when you want to quit the vi /vim editor.